# How to edit grub for many entries of previous kernels with multiple ubuntu installations?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a laptop on which I have installed total 4 operating systems.

1. Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
2. Lubuntu 12.04 64 bit
3. one other variant of Lubuntu(customized by and customized for some users)
4. Windows

My issue is that whenver I get update for kernel, for any of Linux OS, the new kernel entry is directly added into GRUB ..When I had only one OS on my PC all old kernel entries used to be shifted in `previous linux version` option in GRUB but this does not happen when I have multiple Linux installations.

As a result my Grub has almost 12-13 entries and it is very difficult to select one of them..(I know I can remove old kernel versions but still...)

Is there a way to add `previous linux version` options to all installations in GRUB? How to do it?

*Unfortunately I can not add a screenshot!* ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the "Previous Linux versions" submenu isn't being created because of all the different boot points that you have.  But you should be able to add it with the Grub Customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once you have that installed and running, you can manually create the "Previous Linux versions" submenu.  I don't know if future runs of `grub-update` will respect that setting with regards to managing newer kernel versions, but it should at least help you to better manage this issue.

Comment: But I want to add `previous versions` options for every ubunut installation.

Comment: @Nullpointer edit made.