# Grub issue in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I triple boot my machine with Windows, Ubuntu and Kali linux, but kali linux does not shows in grub? How to fix it  and update grub?

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Related:Grub entries for more than one Window OS? http://askubuntu.com/questions/709909/grub-entries-for-more-than-one-window-os

Comment: Related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/422122/how-to-edit-grub-for-many-entries-of-previous-kernels-with-multiple-ubuntu-insta?rq=1